# What value should i insert there?

Tags: c++

i'm trying to set up a driver or something alike for my keyboard. I'm editing somebody elses code according to instructions but one thing is bothering me.

here's code

```
/* to add a new device, simply create a new DEVICE() in this list */
/* Fields are: "Name",VendorID,ProductID,Capabilities */
const libg15_devices_t g15_devices[] = {
    DEVICE("Logitech G510",0x46d,0xc22d, G15_LCD|G15_KEYS|G15_DEVICE_5BYTE_RETURN|G15_DEVICE_IS_SHARED),
    DEVICE("Logitech G15",0x46d,0xc222,G15_LCD|G15_KEYS),
    DEVICE("Logitech G11",0x46d,0xc225,G15_KEYS),
    DEVICE("Logitech Z-10",0x46d,0x0a07,G15_LCD|G15_KEYS|G15_DEVICE_IS_SHARED),
    DEVICE("Logitech G15 v2",0x46d,0xc227,G15_LCD|G15_KEYS|G15_DEVICE_5BYTE_RETURN),
    DEVICE("Logitech Gamepanel",0x46d,0xc251,G15_LCD|G15_KEYS|G15_DEVICE_IS_SHARED),
    DEVICE(NULL,0,0,0)
};


/* return device capabilities */
int g15DeviceCapabilities() {
    if(found_devicetype>-1)
        return g15_devices[found_devicetype].caps;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

The first DEVICE entry is what i'm aiming for and a part of the code i added. here is where i stop.

```
int setLEDs(unsigned int leds)
{
    int retval = 0;
    unsigned char m_led_buf[4] = { 2, 4, 0, 0 };
    unsigned char g510_led_buf[2] = {4, 0};
    m_led_buf[2] = ~(unsigned char)leds;

    if(g15DeviceCapabilities() & G15_DEVICE_G510) {
```

on G15_DEVICE_G510 it stops. i do not know what value i should be replacing it with.

Here's a pastebin of the entire code if this info is insufficient.

[Pastebin Link](http://pastebin.com/N15Fq0S7)

Thanks. :)

EDIT: I found out the functions are defined in another file. here they are.

[Pastebin Link](http://pastebin.com/TnMApcvd)

So what i really need to do is define G15_DEVICE_G510 somehow in that file.

Comment: from what i can see, you want to define `G15_DEVICE_G510` using `G15_LCD`, `G15_KEYS`, `G15_DEVICE_5BYTE_RETURN` and `G15_DEVICE_IS_SHARED` definitions from the second pastebin link you've provided. at least that's what `g15DeviceCapabilities()` will return. also, if you're trying to determine whether `G15_DEVICE_G510` and `g15DeviceCapabilities()` are the same value, i don't think that bitwise AND (&) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it was supposed to be done.

```
#define G15_DEVICE_G510 32
#define G510_STANDARD_KEYBOARD_INTERFACE    0x0
```

then at a later point in the code

```
  int setG510LEDColor(unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b);
```

i managed to find a file with it from [here](http://g15tools.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/g15tools/trunk/libg15/libg15.h?view=markup&pathrev=324)

then i'd need to edit a line i had to this.
DEVICE("Logitech G510",0x46d,0xc22d, `G15_LCD|G15_KEYS|G15_DEVICE_5BYTE_RETURN|G15_DEVICE_IS_SHARED|G15_DEVICE_G510),`
the code for it was originally written by a guy who calls himself "multitude"

So thanks multitude :)